# how to access c# variable inside javascript through EvaluateScriptAsync?

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a c# variable,

```
    double amt = 12;
```

and I have a Javascript piece of code

```
    browser1.EvaluateScriptAsync("var x='<% =amt %>';document.querySelector('.amount').value=x;");
```

which amends the value of the element with <%amt%>. What I want is to pass the actual c# variable's value '12' to be passed into.

and when I do

```js
browser1.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.querySelector('.amount').value='12';");
```

it gives '12' for the value of the element.

now how do I make the element to display whatever the value the c# variable takes?

Comment: I asked it again and answered it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45452320/pass-c-sharp-variable-into-javascript-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//directly insert the c# variable with "+"
browser1.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.querySelector('.amount').value='"+c#variable+"';");
```

I figured out that the c# variable could be directly inserted like in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use diffirent way.Generate a Label element which is sytle visible :false. And you can get the element value.

Like that :

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblHidden" runat="server"  Visible="false"></asp:Label>

 lblHidden.Text = "12";
```

and js

```
var myValue=$('#<% =lblHidden.ClientID %>').val();
browser1.EvaluateScriptAsync("var x=myValue;document.querySelector('.amount').value=x;");
```

Comment: its in a solution project. And this isn't working. As in the OP, I want to pass the c# variable double amt; into the browser1.EvaluateScriptAsync() part. Any help?