# pass C# variable into javascript code

Tags: javascript, c#

I have code lines like this

```
    public double bl = 0;
    browser1.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.querySelector('.amount').value=('#<%= bl%>');");
```

the class with

```
    .amount
```

gets updated with

```
    #<%= bl%>
```

but when I put

```
    "1"
```

instead of

```
    '#<%= bl%>'
```

the field gets updated with

```
    1
```

Now, how do I pass the value of the C# variable into the javascript code?

Comment: So if I understand correct, your input is updated with value `"#<%= bl%>"` but you expect it to be `0`. Yes?

Comment: Why do you want to pass the variable that will be resolved to its value on the page while you can directly pass the value ?

Comment: yes, I need the value 0

Comment: I have a for loop which will decide the value for bl based on various criteria. So I need to pass the variable.

Comment: browser1.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.querySelector('.amount').value=('"+ bl + "');");

Comment: That is because anything inside quotes is string. You will have to concat value of your variable with necessary snippet string

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh, but I came up with the same solution as Etienne except the single quotation marks and the extra brackets. Please see my answer that worked for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for attending people, but this solved me the problem.

```
    browser1.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.querySelector('.amount').value="+bl+";");
```

since the code is in c#, I could split the strings for javascript and insert the actual c# variable without any additional demarcations.

thanks to all who tried.

Comment: I have no idea why it has a downvote. Can you please point out if something is wrong?